# Search a location by name on Bing Map Windows Store App C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can I search a location to get the longitude and latitude by some name e.g: New York?
I am using Bing Map SDK of Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A city I do not believe can be tied to one specific latitude and longitude as it covers a big span of area.  However, using the [Search Manager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306041.aspx) of the Bing Map SDK, you can enter an address in New York per your example to GeoCode and get the the latitude and longitude.

From the msdn class page:

```
// Set the address string to geocode
Bing.Maps.Search.GeocodeRequestOptions requestOptions = new Bing.Maps.Search.GeocodeRequestOptions("1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA");

// Make the geocode request 
Bing.Maps.Search.SearchManager searchManager = myMap.SearchManager;
Bing.Maps.Search.LocationDataResponse response = await searchManager.GeocodeAsync(requestOptions);
```

Hope this helps